# Edit chrome command line args

Tags: google-chrome

When I type in chrome://version there's a box that looks like this:

Command Line:   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --extensions-on-chrome-urls --test-type --load-extension="c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Extensions\chrome\app\37.1329.15.30" --load-component-extension="c:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Extensions\chrome\man" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

It seems to be loading an unwanted extension, and I always have to go uninstall "Max Adblock" from the extension devtools app. Can I edit the builtin command line args to stop it from loading this extension?